# JQuery thumbnail hover highlighting (hiding other thumbnails)

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, highlighting, effect, jquery-hover

I am trying to replicate the effect I found at http://www.rockstargames.com/lanoire/ in the third box. When hovering a thumbnail each other is darkened. 
To implement this, in standard javascript I would handle the onMouseOver event as follows:

- Get references to each thumbnail
- Iterate through each thumbnail but the one that was hovered and change the opacity value

And I would handle the onMouseOut event by setting a timeout after which every thumb would be resetted.

My problem is that I have little knowledge of JQuery, and I don't know if my approach is correct. I'd rather not jump into writing code to end up arguing with the framework. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, however I don't see the need for a timeout (unless you wanted one of course)

Your logic translates into something like this:

```
$("img").hover(function () {
    /* Dim everything but this img: */
    $("img").not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 });
}, function () {
    /* animate all images back to fully visible. */
    $("img").stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 });
});
```

All images are visible upon page load and mouse out. Images that aren't the hovered images are dimmed out.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bp/

Comment: This is amazing, studying this framework it's really worth the effort. Thanks.

Comment: @Davide: No problem! Have fun learning and be sure to look at the top rated questions and answers here on Stack Overflow for some useful stuff `:)`

Comment: I took the freedom to edit your script, adding a black div wrapping each <img> element. This way images fade to the color I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery mousenter and mouseleave to implment the same logic

**step1:** http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

**step2:** Use jquery's this and get the details you want for each record, this gets the details of the current object and you can all the property's.

Then use , jquery .css property's to set the property's

**step3** http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Give each thumbnail a class (for example `.thumbnail`), then use jQuery to set the `opacity`, and apply a `mouseover` and `mouseout` event to each:

```
$(".thumbnail").css("opacity", "0.5").mouseover(function() {
     $(this).css("opacity", "1.0"); 
}).mouseout(function() {
     $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");  
});
```

You can see this working in this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mpvsz/).